Parsing a json column and tokenizing only values in scala spark code
I have a string column named "personData" which contains a json message captured from a kafka topic in a dataframe. I have to parse the json, tokenize only the values in the json (key,value) pairs and replace the "personData" with the tokenized value.
I have a hive udf called "mmtok" which takes 2 parameters, one is the field to be tokenized and the other is the tokenization policy.
I have tried below code and it is working in spark-shell, but is not working when I run the code on cluster. Can someone help me tweak this code to work on the cluster as well?
// Define a tokenization function

def tokenizeJson(jsonValue: JValue): JValue = {
  try {    
    // Define the tokenization logic - here you will tokenize only the values
    jsonValue.transformField {
      case JField(key, JNull) => (key, JNull)
      case JField(key, JString(value)) if value.trim.isEmpty => (key, JString("")) 
      case JField(key, JString(value)) => 
        val tokenValue = Option(spark.sql(s"SELECT mmtok('$value', 'myfunc')").collect()(0)(0)).map(_.toString).getOrElse("")
    (key, JString(tokenValue))
      case JField(key, JObject(innerFields)) => (key, tokenizeJson(JObject(innerFields)))
    }
  } catch {
    case e: Exception => 
      println(s"Error while processing JSON: ${e.getMessage}")
      JNothing
  }
}

// UDF to parse, tokenize and convert the tokenized value to string

val tokenizeJsonUDF = udf((jsonStr: String) => {
    val parsedJson = parse(jsonStr)
    val tokenizedJson = tokenizeJson(parsedJson)
    val tokenizedValue = compact(render(tokenizedJson))
    tokenizedValue
})


// Sample JSON data

val myStr = """{
  "name": "John",
  "address": {
    "street": "5th Avenue",
    "city": {
      "name": "New York",
      "details": {
        "population": "8 million",
        "area": "783.8 km²"
      }
    }
  }
}"""

// Sample data including the json data
val data = Seq("John", "Business", myStr, "US", "Travel")

// Creating a dataframe
val myDF = data.toDF("name", "profession", "personData", "country", "hobby")

// Final dataframe with tokenized values in the Json
val finalDF = myDF.withColumn("personData", tokenizeJsonUDF(col("personData")))

finalDF.show(false)

This code perfectly tokenizes the json values when run in spark-shell but fails when run in cluster environment. Please check and let me know if any tweaks can be done to make it work in cluster environment.

What "does not work" or "fail" means? Do you get an error? Please explain what happens when you run it on the cluster.

@GaëlJ,  I just dont get anything in the column "personData" from the finalDF.

do you get any error on the executor nodes?

I am not seeing any error too

Ok, I checked the logs carefully and see below message
Error while processing JSON:null
